# Use Ajax WordPress Checkbox To Get Template

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a content template based on the checkbox but want to use AJAX to improve my coding structure but not sure how.  I have no prior experience to AJAX so I would really appreciate your help.

```
HTML

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id"content_one">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="content_two">
```

PHP/Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    if ($('#content_one').is(':checked')) {
    <?php get_template('content_one'); ?> //displays a post loop
    }
    if ($('#content_two').is(':checked')) {
    <?php get_template('content_two'); ?> //displays a post loop
    }
});
```

Comment: do you use wordpress for this case?

Comment: yes sir I used WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ajax you need to register the action in wordpress, it would be something like this.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_your_action_name', 'my_fallback_function')
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script');
```

And you need to specify your function here, in the functions.php, it would be something like this

```
function my_fallback_function()
{
    $param = $_GET['param'];
    echo get_template($param);
    wp_die();
}

function my_script()
{
   wp_localize_script(
      'ajaxUrl',
      'ajaxObject',
      array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
   );
}
```

Then we need to specify the ajax call from the client side it would be something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click((e) => {
    const content = $(e.target).val();
    const params = {
      'action': 'your_action_name' // should be the same in the wp_ajax,
      'param': content 
    };
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: ajaxObject.ajax_url
      data: params,
      done(function(respond){
        //append your respond here
      })
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="content_1"/>Content 1</label>
<label for="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="content_2"/>Content 1</label>
```

Comment: do we really still need do declare the jquery.min.js? 
also what does $_GET['param'] do?

Comment: Since we throw the parameter call 'param' in the get url. We need to get the value by using that $_GET['param']. That jquery for just my testing, you can enqueue it in wordpress functions.php

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use var vs const since it get occasionally updated?

Comment: the snippet also create an unexpected error when I try to run it

Comment: Let me edited my answer in better way tonite. Hopefully it helps you better. I use const, because we only use in the context for that click event, and we will  only assign one time for the value.

Comment: @JeVic I modify my code. I think I put too much bracket in the wp_localize_script. Thanks